# Aptana Studio 3 rails debugging stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, aptana3

Just wondering if someone could please advise.

I've had debugging working in Aptana Studio up until today.. and now its stopped working.
I'm not sure why.

- Rails3.0.7
- ruby 1.9.3p448
- OSX Lion

Now, when I try to start the debugger I'm getting the following in the console:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.18, ruby-debug-base19x 0.11) listens on 127.0.0.1:49858
Uncaught exception: undefined method `source' for main:Object
    /Users/pj/railsprojects/researchers.ie/Gemfile:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/pj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
    /Users/pj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `<main>'
```

So, it look like its lost the ability to read a Gemfile ?

In my Gemfile the first few lines are:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth', '0.1.6'

gem 'compass', '>= 0.10.6'
gem 'haml'
gem 'html5-boilerplate'
```

And it appears to be getting hung up on the first line...

Now, I downloaded RubyMine to try it out and its able to debug the same project without a problem.

So, not sure why Aptana Studio would be having the problem.
But it may be related to the fact that command line debugging isn't working either...
When I do 'rails server -debugger' I get errors as follows:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.7 application starting in bugger on http://0.0.0.0:3000
You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your bugger environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/bugger.rb
/Users/pj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in `establish_connection': bugger database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
    from /Users/pj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
    from /Users/pj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/pj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/pj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/pj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Below is my gem list output..I have every debugging gem I can find installed at this stage:

aaronh-chronic (0.3.9)
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (4.0.0, 3.0.12, 3.0.7, 3.0.5)
actionpack (4.0.0, 3.0.12, 3.0.7, 3.0.5)
activemodel (4.0.0, 3.0.12, 3.0.7, 3.0.5)
activerecord (4.0.0, 3.0.12, 3.0.7, 3.0.5)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activeresource (3.0.12, 3.0.7, 3.0.5)
activesupport (4.0.0, 3.0.12, 3.0.7, 3.0.5)
addressable (2.2.4)
annotate (2.4.0)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (4.0.0, 2.0.10)
atomic (1.1.13)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.1.4, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
capistrano (2.5.21)
coffee-rails (4.0.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
columnize (0.3.6)
compass (0.10.6)
daemons (1.1.4)
**debugger (1.6.1)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.3)**
devise (1.1.8)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
execjs (2.0.1)
factory_girl (1.3.3)
factory_girl_rails (1.0)
faker (0.3.1)
faraday (0.5.7)
gravatar_image_tag (1.0.0.pre2)
haml (3.0.25)
haml-rails (0.3.4)
highline (1.6.1)
hike (1.2.3)
hpricot (0.8.4)
html5-boilerplate (0.3.2)
i18n (0.6.5, 0.5.0)
io-console (0.3)
jbuilder (1.5.1)
jquery-rails (3.0.4)
json (1.8.0, 1.6.6, 1.5.5)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
linkedin (0.2.2)
mail (2.5.4, 2.2.20, 2.2.19)
mime-types (1.25, 1.24, 1.18, 1.16)
minitest (4.7.5, 2.5.1)
mocha (0.9.12)
multi_json (1.7.9, 0.0.5)
multipart-post (1.1.0)
mysql2 (0.2.6)
net-ldap (0.1.1)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.0.1)
nifty-generators (0.4.5)
nokogiri (1.4.4)
oa-basic (0.1.6)
oa-core (0.1.6)
oa-enterprise (0.1.6)
oa-oauth (0.1.6)
oa-openid (0.1.6)
oauth (0.4.4)
oauth2 (0.1.1)
omniauth (0.1.6)
polyglot (0.3.3, 0.3.1)
pyu-ruby-sasl (0.0.3.2)
rack (1.5.2, 1.2.8, 1.2.5, 1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-openid (1.2.0)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.5.7)
railroady (1.1.1)
rails (4.0.0, 3.0.12, 3.0.7, 3.0.5)
railties (4.0.0, 3.0.12, 3.0.7, 3.0.5)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.2.2, 0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.12, 3.9.5)
rest-client (1.6.1)
riddle (1.5.7)
rspec (2.6.0, 2.5.0)
rspec-core (2.6.4, 2.5.1)
rspec-expectations (2.6.0, 2.5.0)
rspec-mocks (2.6.0, 2.5.0)
rspec-rails (2.6.1, 2.5.0)
**ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre14, 0.11.30.pre12)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.18, 0.4.17)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)**
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
ruby_parser (2.0.6)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.2)
rubyntlm (0.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.2.10)
sass-rails (4.0.0)
sdoc (0.3.20)
sexp_processor (3.0.5)
spork (0.9.0.rc8)
sprockets (2.10.0)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.8, 1.3.4, 1.3.3)
thin (1.2.11)
thinking-sphinx (2.0.14)
thor (0.18.1, 0.14.6)
thread_safe (0.1.2)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15, 1.4.10, 1.4.9)
turbolinks (1.3.0)
tzinfo (0.3.37, 0.3.32, 0.3.27)
uglifier (2.2.1)
warden (1.0.3)
webrat (0.7.1)
whenever (0.6.8)
will_paginate (3.0.pre2)

Comment: Actually, now I notice that if I open a different file in the editor and then try to Debug, then it finds fault in that file instead of the gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a huge wild goose chase.
The Aptana UI is very confusing.
If you want to debug through a rails app you DON"T click on the debug symbol in the toolbar.

Instead you go to the project explorer on the left hand side and click the gearwheels icon and select Debug Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `rails s --debugger`, it worked for me.